# FORTRAN - Correct values are calculated in simple precision, but erroneous solutions in double precision?

Tags: fortran, double-precision, newtons-method

I have the following code, regarding Newton's method for calculating zeros in multivariable vectorial functions:

```
   program Newton_Method_R_N_R_N_1_Numeric

use Inverse_Matrices

implicit none
integer  :: i, j                            !INDEX
real (kind = 8) :: X(0:501,3)               !VECTORS IN NEWTON METHOD
real (kind = 8) :: A(3,3)                   !JACOBI'S MATRIX FOR EACH VECTOR
integer , parameter :: n = 3                !DIMENSION OF JACOBI'S MATRIZ
real (kind = 8) :: Inv(3,3)                 !INVERSE JACOBI'S MATRIX
real (kind = 8), parameter :: eps = 1D-8    !NEAR-ZERO VALUE
real (kind = 8) :: det                      !DETERMINANT

X(0,:) = (/2.D0,2.D0,2.D0/)

do i = 0, 500
    A = h(X(i,:))
    call LU_Factorization (n, A)
    call Determinant (n, A, det)
    if (abs(det)<eps) then
        exit
    end if
    call Inverse_Matrix (n, A, Inv)
    X(i + 1,:) = X(i,:) - matmul(Inv,g(X(i,:)))
end do

write(*,*) ' A zero of the function is: ', X(i,:)
    read(*,*)

  contains

function g(t)
    implicit none
    real (kind = 8), intent(in) :: t(3)
        real (kind = 8) :: g(3)
        g(1) = t(1)**2 - t(2)**2 + 1.0D0
        g(2) = 2.0D0*t(1)*t(2)
        g(3) = t(3)**2 - 2.0D0
end function g

function g_1(t_1)
    implicit none
    real (kind = 8), intent(in) :: t_1(3)
        real (kind = 8) :: g_1
        g_1 = t_1(1)**2 - t_1(2)**2 + 1.0D0
end function g_1

function g_2(t_2)
    implicit none
    real (kind = 8), intent(in) :: t_2(3)
        real (kind = 8) :: g_2
        g_2 = (2.0D0)*t_2(1)*t_2(2)
end function g_2

function g_3(t_3)
    implicit none
    real (kind = 8), intent(in) :: t_3(3)
        real (kind = 8) :: g_3
        g_3 = t_3(3)**2 - 2.0D0
end function g_3

function h(q)
    implicit none
    real (kind = 8), intent(in) :: q(3)
        real (kind = 8) :: h(3,3)
        real (kind = 8), parameter :: dx = 1D-4 
        real (kind = 8) :: a(3)
        real (kind = 8) :: b(3)
        real (kind = 8) :: c(3) 

        a(1) = dx
        a(2) = 0.D0
        a(3) = 0.D0
        b(1) = 0.D0
        b(2) = dx
        b(3) = 0.D0
        c(1) = 0.D0
        c(2) = 0.D0
        c(3) = dx

        h(1,1) = ((g_1(q + a)) - g_1(q)) / dx
        h(1,2) = ((g_1(q + b)) - g_1(q)) / dx
        h(1,3) = ((g_1(q + c)) - g_1(q)) / dx
        h(2,1) = ((g_2(q + a)) - g_2(q)) / dx
        h(2,2) = ((g_2(q + b)) - g_2(q)) / dx
        h(2,3) = ((g_2(q + c)) - g_2(q)) / dx
        h(3,1) = ((g_3(q + a)) - g_3(q)) / dx
        h(3,2) = ((g_3(q + b)) - g_3(q)) / dx
        h(3,3) = ((g_3(q + c)) - g_3(q)) / dx

end function h

end program
```

In simple precision the solutions are correctly displayed.  The curious thing is that when I make the program write the vectors for each step, the final solution comes up correctly, but simply by eliminating the write statement from the do loop, the final solution comes up as not a number. Double precision seems to be messing with the results, as in simple precision it works properly, and I cannot find what the error might be. Perhaps I am writing the functions wrong in double precision?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

This is the module, if helpful:

```
module Matrices_Inversas_2

    implicit none

contains    

    subroutine Factorizacion_LU (n, A)

    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n            !DIMENSIÓN DEL SISTEMA (matriz de coef.)
    real (kind = 8), intent(inout) :: A(n,n)    !MATRIZ DE COEFICIENTES DEL SISTEMA

        integer :: i, j, k              !ÍNDICES
        real (kind = 8) :: V(n), W(n)               !VECTORES AUXILIARES

        !FACTORIZACIÓN LU
        do k = 1, n

            !COLUMNAS
            do i = 1, (k - 1)
                V(i) = A(k,i)
            end do
            do j = k, n
                do i = 1, (k - 1)
                    W(i) = A(i,j)
                end do
                A(k,j) = A(k,j) - dot_product(V,W)
            end do

            !FILAS
            do i = 1, (k - 1)
                W(i) = A(i,k)
            end do
            do i = (k + 1), n
                do j = 1, (k - 1)
                    V(j) = A(i,j)
                end do
                A(i,k) = (A(i,k) - dot_product(V,W)) / A(k,k)
            end do

        end do

    end subroutine Factorizacion_LU

    subroutine Sustitucion_Directa (n, A, B, C, V)

    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n                !DIMENSIÓN DEL SISTEMA  
    real (kind = 8), intent(inout) :: A(n,n)        !MATRICES DEL SISTEMA
    real (kind = 8), intent (in) :: B(n)            !MATRIZ DE TÉRMINOS INDEPENDIENTES
    real (kind = 8), intent(out) :: C(n)            !MATRIZ DE INCÓGNITAS
    real (kind = 8), intent(out) :: V(n)            !VECTOR AUXILIAR

        integer :: i, j                     !ÍNDICES EN LAS MATRICES
        real (kind = 8) :: s                            !SUMATORIO

        do i = 1, n
            V(i) = A(i,i)
            A(i,i) = 1.D0
        end do

        !SUSTITUCIÓN DIRECTA
        C(1) = B(1) / A(1,1)
            do i = 2, n
                s = 0.D0
                do j = 1, (i - 1)
                    s = s + A(i,j)*C(j)
                end do
                C(i) = (B(i) - s) / A(i,i)
            end do

    end subroutine Sustitucion_Directa

    subroutine Sustitucion_Regresiva (n, A, C, X, V)

    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n            !DIMENSIÓN DEL SISTEMA
    real (kind = 8), intent(inout) :: A(n,n)    !MATRIZ DE COEFICIENTES
    real (kind = 8), intent(in) :: C(n)         !MATRIZ DE TÉRMINOS INDEPENDIENTES
    real (kind = 8), intent(out) :: X(n)        !MATRIZ DE INCÓGNITAS
    real (kind = 8), intent(in) :: V(n)         !VECTOR AUXILIAR

        integer :: i,j                  !ÍNDICES EN LAS MATRICES
        real (kind = 8) :: s                        !SUMATORIO EN SUSTITUCIÓN REGRESIVA

        do i = 1, n
            A(i,i) = V(i)
        end do

        !SUSTITCUIÓN REGRESIVA
        X(n) = C(n) / A(n,n)
        do i = (n - 1), 1, -1
            s = 0.D0
            do j = (i + 1), n
                s = s + A(i,j) * X(j)
            end do
            X(i) = (C(i) - s) / A(i,i)
        end do

    end subroutine Sustitucion_Regresiva

    subroutine Matriz_inversa (n, A, Inv)

    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n            !DIMENSIÓN DEL SISTEMA
    real (kind = 8), intent(inout) :: A(n,n)    !MATRIZ DE LA QUE HALLAR LA INVERSA
    real (kind = 8), intent(out) :: Inv(n,n)    !INVERSA

        integer :: i, j                 !ÍNDICES
        real (kind = 8) :: B(n)                     !MATRIZ DE TÉRMINOS INDEPENDIENTES
        real (kind = 8) :: C(n)                     !MATRIZ INTERMEDIA DE INCÓGNITAS
        real (kind = 8) :: X(n)                     !MATRIZ DE INCÓGNITAS
        real (kind = 8) :: V(n)                     !VECTOR AUXILIAR

        do i = 1, n
            B = 0.D0
            B(i) = 1.D0
            call Sustitucion_Directa (n, A, B, C, V)
            call Sustitucion_Regresiva (n, A, C, X, V)
            do j = 1, n
                Inv(j,i) = X(j)
            end do
        end do

    end subroutine Matriz_inversa

    subroutine Determinante (n, A, det)

    integer, intent(in) :: n        !DIMENSIÓN DEL SISTEMA
    real (kind = 8), intent(inout) :: A(n,n)!MATRIZ DE ENTRADA
    real(kind = 8), intent(out) :: det      !VALOR DEL DETERMINANTE

        integer :: i                            !ÍNDICE

        det = 1.D0
        do i = 1, n
            det = det * A(i,i)
        end do

    end subroutine Determinante

    end module
```

Comment: is the  Inverse_Matrices module something standard/documented?

Comment: Yes, but it's only when I alter what is in the main program that the solutions vary. The whole module is in double precision aswell. I'm near-certain it is something to do with the way the double-precision expressions are written in the main program.

Comment: the `write` causing some apparently unrelated issue speaks of an array out of bounds or using an uninitialized value, or similar, so  It could well be related to the module functions. Try turning on full bounds checking and so on.   As  an aside it would be preferable to reverse the indices on `X` to `X(3,*)` so that the components of each vector are aligned in memory.

Comment: `h(x)` is the derivative of `g(x)`?

Comment: Can you show us what the expected result is and what you get.

Comment: I am looking at some of the module and will post it if needed.

Comment: h(x) is the Jacobi matrix of g(x). I expect something close to (0,1,sqrt(2)), and I get either NaN on all three values, or very large numbers, depending on different ways I have tried to write the expressions in double precision. In simple the solutions are correct.

Comment: Which debugging options did you try? (E.g., `gfortran -Wall -fcheck=all -g -fbacktrace` or `ifort -warn -check -g -traceback`)

Answer (score 1):

You have provided us a module `Matrices_Inversas_2` containing apparently-Spanish named procedures, but your program uses a module called `Inverse_Matrices`, so we still do not have a fully-compilable set of code to work with.

You also have not specified what you consider to be 'correctly displayed'.

I made the obvious changes to your module code in order to get your procedure names to match up and compiled using `nagfor -kind=byte -u -C=all -C=undefined -gline`. Running, I get

```
mod.f90:
[NAG Fortran Compiler normal termination]
test.f90:
Warning: test.f90, line 93: Unused local variable J
[NAG Fortran Compiler normal termination, 1 warning]
Loading...
Runtime Error: mod.f90, line 27: Reference to undefined variable V
Program terminated by fatal error
mod.f90, line 27: Error occurred in MATRICES_INVERSAS_2:FACTORIZACION_LU
test.f90, line 18: Called by NEWTON_METHOD_R_N_R_N_1_NUMERIC
Abort (core dumped)
```

You are attempting a `dot_product` of two size-`n` arrays (`V` and `W`) for which it seems from your code that only the first `(k-1)` elements are initialized. If I replace both of your `dot_product` calls with `dot_product(V(1:(k-1)),W(1:(k-1)))` then the program runs to completion and displays

```
A zero of the function is:    0.0000000000000000   1.0000000000000000   1.4142135623730951
```